# how to check string variable value equal to blank in if condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have selected v="value" in select option but isPendChk variable is not going to true

```
var isPendChk = false;
    $('#pendingCategoryId').each(function(){
    var v = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    if (v !== null && v !== ''){
      isPendChk = true;
    }
  });
  if(isPendChk){
      $(".radio").addClass("chkPoint").prop("disabled", true);
      $(".checkbox").addClass("chkPoint").prop("disabled", true);
   }
```

Comment: `$('#pendingCategoryId').each(function(){` will not work because `id` can't be repetitive. they need to be unique

Comment: As well as change condition to `if (v !== ''){
      isPendChk = true;
    }else{ isPendChk = false; }`

Comment: No need to add additional code with variables, simply run a change function with each to iterate, use class and/or tag elements as selectors and then disable your entries. I would suggest adding an unlock button so the user can change entries before submission. See my answer for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I iterate over the elements using .each() on click and find the value that is selected within the group of option siblings. Once we find the selected option, we disable the submit button and the element.  You could also disable the element as well, simply change the selector to the id you wish to disable. Could also use .change() if you want to fire before a submit button has been clicked.

**NOTE:** Make sure you loop over an element with `.each()` or the class of a list of elements.

***From MDN source:*** *The **.each()** method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the element.*

So when you use an `ID` in your .each loop, it will not work as expected because an ID is unique to one element, or should be. Use classes or element tags in `.each()`.

***BONUS:*** Set a button to unlock so user can make changes to their entries if they accidentally entered that wrong info.

```js
// Using .click() with .each(selector = element tag)
$('#submit').click(function() {
  $( "option" ).each(function() {  
    if($(this).find("select option:selected")) {
       $("#submit, #cars").prop("disabled", true);
    }
  });
});

// Using .change() with .each(selector = class) added button to unlock for user sake!
$('#people').change(function() {
  $( ".ppl" ).each(function() {  
    if($(this).find(".ppl:selected")) {
       $("#people").prop("disabled", true);
    }
    $('#change').click(function(){
       $("#people, #cars, #submit").prop("disabled", false);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select id="cars">
  <option class="opt" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option class="opt" value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option class="opt" value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option class="opt" value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit values">
<br><br>
<select id="people">
  <option class="ppl" value="John">John</option>
  <option class="ppl" value="Sally">Sally</option>
  <option class="ppl" value="Jack">Jack</option>
  <option class="ppl" value="Jim">Jim</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="change" name="change" value="Unlock?">
```